# How to collect IP addresses of specific domain as many as possible?

Tags: dns, ip, nslookup, dig

How to collect IP addresses of specific domain as many as possible?

Using nslookup or dig command, there is limitation to collect whole IP address.

How can I collect IP address that DNS server is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use this site https://www.robtex.com

[Robtex](https://www.robtex.com) gives you some deep information on their website.